# ActiveAdmin : member_action "approve" on User model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I want to add a member_action named approve on my User model in ActiveAdmin. I looked at docs but everything is different and i'm quite confused about how to do it. Until now, I've only make it to show the approve link (next to View, Edit and Delete).

admin/user.rb :

```
member_action :approve, method: :post do
    user = User.find params[:id]
    user.approve!
    redirect_to admin_user_path(user), notice: "Approved!"
  end
```

and to show the link:

```
actions defaults: true do |user|
    link_to 'Approve',approve_admin_user_path(user)
end
```

models/user.rb :

```
def approve!
    update(bio_validee: true)
end
```

When I click on the link , I have a Routing Error with :

```
No route matches [GET] "/admin/users/21/approve"
```

Here what `rake routes` does (for admin/users routes):

```
approve_admin_user POST       /admin/users/:id/approve(.:format)              admin/users#approve
        batch_action_admin_users POST       /admin/users/batch_action(.:format)             admin/users#batch_action
                     admin_users GET        /admin/users(.:format)                          admin/users#index
                                 POST       /admin/users(.:format)                          admin/users#create
                  new_admin_user GET        /admin/users/new(.:format)                      admin/users#new
                 edit_admin_user GET        /admin/users/:id/edit(.:format)                 admin/users#edit
                      admin_user GET        /admin/users/:id(.:format)                      admin/users#show
                                 PATCH      /admin/users/:id(.:format)                      admin/users#update
                                 PUT        /admin/users/:id(.:format)                      admin/users#update
                                 DELETE     /admin/users/:id(.:format)                      admin/users#destroy
```

Have I done something wrong? What do I have to add ?
Furthermore, I don't know if I have to use GET, POST, or PUT in

`member_action :approve, method: :post`

I don't really get the difference in that case.

Comment: what does `rake routes` show?

Comment: I've edited my post with what rake routes returns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
member_action :approve, method: :put do
  resource.approve!
  redirect_to admin_user_path(resource), notice: "Approved!"
end
```

And ....

```
actions defaults: true do |user|
  link_to 'Approve',approve_admin_user_path(user), method: :put
end
```

Comment: Glad to help. Also you may want to check out batch actions. They are useful for things like this especially when an admin user will often be approving many items in one sitting.